# Compare table A With table B Before INSERT data A INTO B

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables below:

```
A) inventory
(`id`, `item`, `qty_left`, `qty_min`, `qty_max`, `cat_no`, `supplier`) VALUES
(1, 'Orange', 6, 10, 50, 1001, 'ACOMP'),
(2, 'Apple', 4, 10, 20, 1002, 'BCOMP'),
(3, 'Pear', 80, 20, 100, 1003, 'ACOMP'),
(4, 'Durian', 90, 60, 100, 1004, 'CCOMP');

B) reorder_in_process (`id`, `item`, `to_order`, `cat_no`, `supplier`) VALUES
(Empty)
```

If I run query below, (With PHP, SQL & JS) to put item in low qty to table B,

```
(Say q = BCOMP)
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE qty_left<=qty_min AND supplier='$q'
$to_order = $qty_max -$qty_left;
INSERT INTO reorder_in_process VALUES (NULL, '$item', '$to_order', '$cat_no', '$q')";
```

Table B will be like this:

```
reorder_in_process (`id`, `item`, `to_order`, `cat_no`, `supplier`) VALUES
(72, 'Apple', 16, 1002, 'BCOMP');
```

Now the problem is, if I run the above query again,

Table B will be like this:

```
reorder_in_process (`id`, `item`, `to_order`, `cat_no`, `supplier`) VALUES
(72, 'Apple', 16, 1002, 'BCOMP');
(73, 'Apple', 16, 1002, 'BCOMP');
```

I don't want that to happen.So, what can I do?

```
1) if row containing(cat_no ='1002') already exist in table B, new INSERT of
 (cat_no='1002') will not be allowed/happened,
2) if row containing(cat_no) that not exist in table B, new INSERT is allowed.
```

Pls suggest. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea, tat's why I ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a unique index on the `cat_no` column in table B and do an `INSERT IGNORE` instead.